# Python: don't display 'choices' with argparse

Tags: python, parameters, argparse

With **argparse**, I have the following line:

```
parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter", type=str, default=None, nargs='+',
                        help="some option",
                        choices=allValues.keys()
                        )
```

The resulting `help` message shows all values in `allValues`:

> -p {a ,b ,c , d, e, f, g, h, i, l, m; a ,b ,c , d, e, f, g, h, i, l, m} [{a ,b ,c , d, e, f, g, h, i, l, m} ...], --parameter {a ,b ,c , d,
>   e, f, g, h, i, l, m; a ,b ,c , d, e, f, g, h, i, l, m} [{a ,b ,c , d,
>   e, f, g, h, i, l, m; a ,b ,c , d, e, f, g, h, i, l, m} ...]
>                            some option

Can I **remove** `{a ,b ,c , d, e, f, g, h, i, l, m; a ,b ,c , d, e, f, g, h, i, l, m}` from above and **just display** the **name** of the parameter and the **help** message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `metavar` argument::

```
parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter", type=str, default=None, nargs='+',
                    help="some option",
                    choices=allValues.keys(),
                    metavar='PARAMETER'
                    )
```

This will give::

```
-p PARAMETER, --parameter PARAMETER some option
```

If you don't want to show a metavariable at all you could consider passing `''` to `metavar`.  Otherwise, I believe you will have to create your own custom formatter classes and pass that to the `ArgumentParser`.

Comment: Is this compatible with `python3`? I see no change in behavior

Comment: Yes, it is available on python 3

Comment: For positional parameters using metavar won't display the choices. I didn't test `choices=` help for optional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

On [lesspass](https://github.com/lesspass/lesspass/pull/411) we used both `metavar` and a custom `type` to **control the help and error message** was displayed:

- Use `metavar` to  get a nicer help message
- Use custom `type` to control error message

### Output

#### Error message

```
env ❯ python3 lesspass/core.py  site login masterpassword --lowercase --digits --length 2
usage: lesspass SITE [LOGIN] [MASTER_PASSWORD] [OPTIONS]
core.py: error: argument -L/--length: 2 is out of range, choose in [5-35]
```

#### Help message

```
env ❯ python3 lesspass/core.py  --help
  …
  -L [5-35], --length [5-35]
                        password length (default: 16, min: 5, max: 35)
  …
```

### How to do it?

#### Custom Type

```
def range_type(value_string):
    value = int(value_string)
    if value not in range(5, 35+1):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%s is out of range, choose in [5-35]" % value)
    return value
```

#### `add_argument` Declaration

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-L",
    "--length",
    default=16,
    choices=range(5, 35+1),
    type=range_type,
    help="password length (default: 16, min: 5, max: 35)",
    metavar='[5-35]'
```

)